# if $\alpha \beta$ is successor $\Rightarrow \alpha$ is successor y $\beta$ is successor

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory, ordinals

Please could you look at the demonstration I propose below for this implication and tell me if I am wrong.

What other way or idea is there to demonstrate the implication?

Proof:

The implication is equivalent to showing that:

if $\alpha$ is limit or $\beta$ is limit $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha \beta$ is limit

Proof by reductio ad absurdum, be $\alpha \beta$ successor, them  $\alpha \beta=\lambda+1$.

Case $\alpha$ limit:

$\alpha=\sup \{\gamma: \gamma<\alpha\}$ them for all $\gamma<\alpha$ so that $\gamma+1<\alpha$. In particular let $\alpha \beta=\lambda+1$ $=\gamma+1$, them $\alpha \beta<\alpha$ and it's false;  because, let $1<\beta$ them $\alpha<\alpha \beta$ when $0<\alpha$. If $\beta=0$ or $\beta=1$ then $\alpha \beta$ is limit. and if $\alpha$=0 then $\alpha \beta<0$, it's false

Comment: If $\alpha \beta$ is successor, there is no reason that it's successor of an ordinal $< \alpha$. Hence you cannot conclude $\alpha \beta < \alpha$.

Comment: Hint: first show this is true for $\beta$ is limit, then consider the case $\beta$ is successor. BTW: $\alpha, \beta$ have to be $\neq 0$.

Comment: @Ulli Thank you for your answer.